# TinyMce 4 + ResponsiveFileManager cross domain : Blocked a frame with origin

Tags: javascript, tinymce, responsive-filemanager

Does anyone know how to make Responsive File Manager (http://www.responsivefilemanager.com) work with tinyMCE 4 with a subdomain (crooss domain)?
Their website says that it's possible to  do it, but I can't figure out how because I'm blocked with this message (Chrome console) :

Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "mywebsite.local" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

For info I want to store the images on a domain such as mywebsite.local and TinyMCE is on a subdomain : admin.mywebsite.local

Here's my code :

```
    // TinyMCE
    tinymce.init({
    ...

    // Responsivefilemanager
    filemanager_crossdomain: true,
    external_filemanager_path:"http://mywebsite.local/filemanager/",
    external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "http://mywebsite.local/filemanager/plugin.min.js"},

    ...
 });
```

Please help it's been hours I'm trying to figure this out ! 
Thanx !

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are seeing is that you are trying to make a CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) request and the server that hosts your File Manager is not returning headers to allow a CORS request.

This site provides a nice overview of setting up CORS:  https://enable-cors.org/